# Running Python commands in Go

Tags: go

I am trying following code:

```
package main
import ("fmt";  "log"; "os/exec")
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/python3.5",  "-c",
        "import easygui as eg; print('Hello world'); eg.msgbox(msg='Hi there'); print('from Golang')")
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {     log.Fatal(err)  }
    fmt.Printf(string(out)) }
```

I am trying it to print on terminal first, then show a gui messagebox, then again print on terminal.

However, it first shows a message box, then does both print statements.

How can this be solved?

Comment: exec 3 different commands?

Comment: I tried but reassigning cmd variable is not working.

Comment: And how is this a Python question exactly ??? (=> tag removed).

Comment: I agree with your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program runs `cmd.CombinedOutput()`, which launches the Python script (as a side effect displaying the message box) and collects its stdout into a variable; then does a single `fmt.Printf` to print out the program's output.  That leads to the sequencing you're seeing.

If you call `cmd.StdoutPipe()` then you will get an `io.Reader` that has the script's stdout instead.  It's your responsibility to read from the pipe and copy to your own process's stdout; the [os/exec documentation has an example](https://godoc.org/os/exec#example-Cmd-StdoutPipe).  You need to `cmd.Start()`, then read everything from the pipe, then `cmd.Wait()` to clean up after yourself.

You may also be able to directly assign `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout`, then `cmd.Run()`.  In this case you won't be able to see the output within your program, but you also won't have to copy it around.